# Android Emulator Screen Size Problem

Tags: android, eclipse, size, screen, emulation

I am using a Eclipse to build a simple android app. After following the steps given in previous answers to change the screen size, when I run the the app it still defaults to the standard size. This size is lager than my screen making it hard to work with. run/run configurations/target allow you to choose a target and adjust the target to the correct size. If you run from this screen it will open the emulator in the correct size, but not actually run the app. run/run (crt + f11) will then open the app in the default large size seemingly not applying the changes. If any one has a solution I would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start your AVD from AVD manager and then select scale display to real size and then give the screen size to 3 and click start/lunch.

Comment: This will open the emulator but it will not actually run the program you have written

Comment: yes after opening the emulator you can run your application from eclipse but make sure that you have set you application run configuration to manual.

Comment: nice, it works. I was being impatient and not allowing it to load fully. After the emulator is loaded you can choose to run it on a device that is currently running. Thanks